# Converting 2d array to Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs

I have this 2d Array

```
"coordinates" : [ 
            [ 
                [ 
                    41.5311338460033, 
                    -8.61901849508286
                ], 
                [ 
                    41.5311338460033, 
                    -8.61851692199707
                ], 
                [ 
                    41.5312944769825, 
                    -8.61851692199707
                ], 
                [ 
                    41.5312944769825, 
                    -8.61901849508286
                ], 
                [ 
                    41.5311338460033, 
                    -8.61901849508286
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

And im trying to convert it to

```
const paths = [
      { lat: 41.53113384600326, lng: -8.619018495082855 },
      { lat: 41.53113384600326, lng: -8.61851692199707 },
      { lat: 41.53129447698251, lng: -8.61851692199707 },
      { lat: 41.53129447698251, lng: -8.619018495082855 },
      { lat: 41.53113384600326, lng: -8.619018495082855 }
    ];
```

Im trying to do this method

```
let test = this.props.places.places.map(place => {
      place.location.coordinates.map((c,i) => {
        console.log('MAP TEST', c);
        return {
          lat: c[i],
          lng: c[i]
        };
      });
    });
```

console.log returns both the locations from my two documents but when i console test i receive num.
Anyone has any idea on how i can transform that array into a **lat**, **lng** object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the array in the wrong way.

If it's a 2D array, you could try using [`.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

```js
const obj = {
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [41.5311338460033, -8.61901849508286],
            [41.5311338460033, -8.61851692199707],
            [41.5311338460033, -8.61851692199707],
            [41.5311338460033, -8.61901849508286],
            [41.5311338460033, -8.61901849508286],
        ],
        [
            [41.5311338460033, -8.61901849508286],
            [41.5311338460033, -8.61851692199707],
            [41.5311338460033, -8.61851692199707],
            [41.5311338460033, -8.61901849508286],
            [41.5311338460033, -8.61901849508286],
        ],
    ]
}

const paths = obj.coordinates.map(cord => cord.map(x => ({lat: x[0], lng: x[1]}))).flat()

console.log(paths)
```

For you case, you should do

```
let test = this.props.places.places.map(place => {
    // return addded
    return place.location.coordinates.map((c, i) => {
        console.log('MAP TEST', c);
        return c.map(x => ({
            lat: x[i],
            lng: x[i]
        }))
    }).flat();
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind coordinates is an array coming from my database and i have more coordinates from other documents that i want to go through

Comment: your doing the const obj that i cant do here

Comment: @FCorreia The `const obj` is just an example to show you the logic. Please check my edit where I added the code inside you example. Don't forget to `return` inside `.map`